# React Testing Library: How to mock dom-ref properties without them being overwritten?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, unit-testing, react-testing-library

I am testing a react component that renders a container with `overflow:hidden` with children, which has an effect hook that calculates the visible elements.
I want to test that feature by mocking the `clientWidth` value of the container ref, but I can't get it to work. **My mock of `useRef` gets called but my mocked value gets overwritten after the first render.**

**How do I mock the value of `clientWidth` or is there another way to test this behavior?**

[Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-testing-with-mocked-ref-properties-szdepb)

My component:

```ts
function OverflowingComponent() {
    const divRef = React.useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);
    const [visibleChildren, setVisibleChildren] = React.useState(0);

    React.useEffect(() => {
        if (divRef.current) {
            const containerChildren = divRef.current.children;
            const maxVisibleChildren = Math.round(divRef.current.clientWidth / containerChildren[0].clientWidth);
            setVisibleChildren(
                containerChildren.length < maxVisibleChildren ? containerChildren.length : maxVisibleChildren
            );
        }
    }, []);

    return (
        <>
            <label>{visibleChildren} elements are visible!</label>
            <div ref={divRef} style={{ display: 'flex', overflow: 'hidden' }}>
                <div style={{ width: 50, flexShrink: 0 }}>foo</div>
                <div style={{ width: 50, flexShrink: 0 }}>bar</div>
                <div style={{ width: 50, flexShrink: 0 }}>boo</div>
                <div style={{ width: 50, flexShrink: 0 }}>far</div>
            </div>
        </>
    );
}
```

My test:

```ts
describe('OverflowingComponent', () => {
    it('only 3 elements should be visible with a container with of 200px', () => {
        jest.spyOn(React, 'useRef').mockImplementation(() => ({
            current: {
                clientWidth: 150
            }
        }));

        render(<OverflowingComponent />);

        expect(screen.getByText('3 elements are visible!')).toBeInTheDocument();
    });
});
```

Since the ref-mock does not work the test always fails with:

> Unable to find an element with the text: 3 elements are visible!. This could be because the text is broken up by multiple elements. In this case, you can provide a function for your text matcher to make your matcher more flexible.
>
> Ignored nodes: comments, script, style
>
> NaN
> elements are visible!